# Awk regex pattern matching with space

Tags: awk

I have a file `fruits`:

```
ap ple 
ora nge 
pe ar
gra pes
bro ccoli
tom ato
ap ache
```

I'd like to make an awk script to check how many fruits are there in the file.

I have tried

```
awk -F: '/ap|ora|pe|gra ple|nge|ar|pes/ {sum+=1} END {print sum+0}' fruits
```

and it should return 4, since 4 of their pairs are exact match, but they're returning 5 I think due to `ap ache`. Does the space not register in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regular expression `ap|ora|pe|gra ple|nge|ar|pes` matches

`ap` or `ora` or `pe` **or** `gra ple` **or** `nge` or `ar` or `pes`

You need to add some grouping to match two separate alternates with space inbetween:

```
$ awk '/(ap|ora|pe|gra) (ple|nge|ar|pes)/' fruits 
ap ple 
ora nge 
pe ar
gra pes

$ awk '/(ap|ora|pe|gra) (ple|nge|ar|pes)/ {sum+=1} END{print sum}' fruits 
4
```

Note that you don't need to set `-F` to a non-whitespace value since `/pattern/` matches the whole record by default.

Comment: or check for `$1 ~ /^(ap|ora|pe|gra)$/ && $2 ~ /^(ple|nge|ar|pes)$/` (with or without `^$`. But that would also match `graple` and `apar` etc... So maybe something like `$1 $2 ~ /^(apple|orange|pear|grapes)$/` ???

Comment: It should be clear that this will also match `ap ar` or `ora pes` or `gra ple` or many other pairs which **are not fruits**.

Comment: Maybe the OP should be using  `awk '/^(ap ?ple|ora ?nge|pe ?ar|gra ?pes) ?$/{c++}END{print c}'`.`